# Can't detach R packages using paste()

Tags: r

I'm working on some functions in an R project for attaching and detaching packages, and I'm having trouble getting `paste()` to work inside the `detach()` function (this is eventually going to be part of a for loop):

```
> library(ggplot2)
> (.packages())
 [1] "ggplot2"   "stringr"   "readr"     "stats"     "graphics" 
 [6] "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"
> detach(paste("package", "ggplot2", sep = ":"), unload = TRUE)
Error in detach(paste("package", "ggplot2", sep = ":"), unload = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'name' argument
```

But it works fine if I do this:

```
> detach("package:ggplot2", unload = TRUE)
> (.packages())
[1] "stringr"   "readr"     "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices"
[6] "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"
```

And `paste()` is returning the right thing:

```
> paste("package", "ggplot2", sep = ":")
[1] "package:ggplot2"
```

So I'm not sure what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `character.only = TRUE` and `force = TRUE`

```
detach(paste("package", "ggplot2", sep = ":"), unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

It may print some warning but detach `ggplot2`.